# US to INDIA via Zurich, Do I need transit visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am an Indian Passport holder, traveling from Chicago to New Delhi INDIA with Layover in Zurich of 2 hours. My US Visa is expired which is why I am traveling back to get the new visa stamped. Will I also need a Transit visa for Zurich?
I have all the visa documents to show the approval through which stamping will be done in INDIA.